# How to combine two methods in JAVA?

Tags: java, java-8, boolean

I have two methods which returns two values. The method is mostly same so I was thinking to combine them to single method and manipulate to return different values but not sure will it be useful?

Can someone tell me is this method can be converted to single ?

```
private boolean getFirst(List<Apples> apples) {

        boolean isOrange  = false;
        if (apples != null) {
            for (Apples apple : apples) {
                String type = apple.getFruit();
                boolean isApple = StringUtils.equalsIgnoreCase(type, ORANGE);
                if (!isApple) {
                    isOrange = true;
                }
            }
        }
        return isOrange;
    }



 private boolean getSecond(List<Apples> apples) {

        boolean isAppletype  = false;
        if (apples != null) {
            for (Apples apple : apples) {
                 String type = apple.getFruit();
                boolean isApple = StringUtils.equalsIgnoreCase(type, ORANGE);
                 if (isApple) {
                    isAppletype = true;
                }
            }
        }
        return isAppletype;
    }
```

Comment: `boolean isApple = StringUtils.equalsIgnoreCase(type, ORANGE);` is a bit weird. It is an apple if the type is ORANGE?

Comment: How come there are oranges in a list of apples anyway? Can you tell more about the code? This sounds like a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: The name of the class shoud be `Apple` anyway. Otherwise one creates the illusion that the object contains multiple apples.

Comment: By the way, this is another example of unnecessary 3rd part library usage: `type.equalsIgnoreCase(ORANGE)` does not require any `StringUtils` class…

Answer (score 4):

You can use streams for this:

```
List<Apple> list = ...;

// First method
list.stream().anyMatch((e) -> !StringUtils.equalsIgnoreCase(e.getFruit(), ORANGE));
// Second method
list.stream().anyMatch((e) -> StringUtils.equalsIgnoreCase(e.getFruit(), ORANGE));
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can for sure merge those methods into a new one that can be more generic for what it does...

for example, if I rename the method to **isThisFruitPresentInTheList** please forgive the name convention I use :) ...

Then you can pass a list to the method, and as a 2nd parameter the fruit you are looking for, the method will return true if a fruit is present in the list, false otherwise...

## Example:

```
 private boolean isThisFruitPresentInTheList(List<Apples> apples, String f) {
        if (apples != null) {
            for (Apples apple : apples) {
                if (f.equalsIgnoreCase(apple.getFruit())) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

and you can invoke the method like doing....

```
isThisFruitHere(List<Apples> apples, APPLES)
isThisFruitHere(List<Apples> apples, ORANGES)
```

Answer (score 0):

Given

```
private boolean containsType(List<Apples> apples, boolean orangeType) {
    if (apples != null) {
        for (Apples apple : apples) {
            String type = apple.getFruit();
            boolean isOrange = StringUtils.equalsIgnoreCase(type, ORANGE);
            if (orangeType == isOrange)
                return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Your methods would be equivalent as follows

- `getFirst(apples)` => `containsType(apples, false)`
- `getSecond(apples)` => `containsType(apples, true)`